# On AWS Amazon server, how can i increase time of php?

Tags: php

i have a problem. 
I have a free space on aws amazon cloud with a machine to build a web app. I found the php ini and i had set up max_execution_time to 900, max_input_time to -1 and the time of socket to 900 but it didn't work.
I have to run a script on php code that do a check to control if link is online or not (call the server of openload). It works if the time is below 1 min but not if is above. Why? 
it said me `Gateway Timeout
The gateway did not receive a timely response from the upstream server or application.`
What is my mistake?
Thanks a lot

Comment: If you're getting a gateway timeout, then you'll more likely need to make a configuration change to a load balancer or proxy, rather than PHP itself.

Comment: try to modify the wait condition

Comment: how can i do it? thanks

Comment: have you deployed your application through cloud formation (beanstalk) or setup manually

Comment: i don't understand your message. I created a web app and i modified the code of php.ini

Comment: nothing of new? can someone help me?